# using a method that is only defined in the subclasses - JAVA

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I am trying to implement a plugin for a java project where I only have access to the interfaces.
The project has following structure:

superclass: A 
subclasses: B, C, E and F

All the subclasses B, C, D, E and F extend the class A and have a method called "execute()". This method is not defined in the superclass(A).

Now I want to implement a method in my plugin called "doSomething()" that uses the "execute()" method of the subclasses B, C, D, E and F.
And I don't want to duplicate the same method 4 times (for each subclass).

When I put the superclass (A) as parameter, I cannot access to the method defined in the subclasses:

```
public void doSomething(A a) {
   a.execute()
}
```

I also tried to generify the doSomething() method and define multiple upper bounds like this:

```
public <T extends B, C, D, E, F> void doSomething(T t) {
   t.execute();
}
```

But it is not possible to define more than one class in the upper bounds, since it's not possible to have types, which inherit from more than one super-class.

Is there any way to implement the doSomething() method without duplicating it or changing the source code of the subclasses? 
**Please note that I cannot change any of the given classes (A, ... F).**

Comment: How about you have the subclasses implement an interface called `Executable` that defines `execute()`. Then you can do `public <T extends A & Executable>` in `doSomething`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

probably somehow like that:

```
public static void doSomething(Object object) {
        try {
            Method method = object.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("execute", null);
            method.invoke(object);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

A b = new B();
doSomething(b);
```

Comment: This seems to be working!
since there is no better solution for the problem, I'll approve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple, declare parent as `abstract` and declare `execute()` as `abstract` as well in that class. Then declare the `doSomething` in parent as well but make it not abstract. Then call `execute()` from `doSomething()`

```
abstract class Parent {
 abstract void execute();
void doSomething() {
 execute();
}
}

class B extends Parent {
 void execute() {
  //do some specific things for B
 }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't change any of the given classes (A,..,F)

Comment: @Siraj'eddineBenzineb you didn't specify that important thing in your problem statement

Comment: But which class then you can modify?

Comment: I just added that to the description. 
And I am implementing the doSomething() method in a random class in my plugin.